# How to display the selected data from this form?

Tags: php, mysql, html

So this is part of my code :

```
echo "<form name='whatever' action='next.php' method='get'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qsq))
{
echo"<input type='checkbox' name='choice[]' value='" . $row['question_id'] . "' /> ". `$row['question_text'] . '<br />';`

}
echo"<br>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit' /></form>";
```

What should i do in the next.php ? I'm thinking to put the selected info in an array and display it. Then store the selected results in a table.But i am not sure with the codes.I am beginner in php can someone help me with the coding ?Thanks in advance!

Comment: You only want to display them? It does not make much sense. Please give more details. - You are using qotation marks very incosistntly, try thnking them over.

Comment: There are other functions too but i will try to do it myself.But now i am really lost in coding arrays to get the selected values.The code above will be a list of selections.Once user select it,he will click the button to go to the next.php.In this next.php i want to get the values selected.

Comment: Ok i just want to echo the selected values from the form above.I'm really lost please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I cleaned up your code a little bit. (Using single quoutes around HTML trributes is uncanny).

```
echo ('<form name="whatever" action="next.php" method="get">');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($qsq)) {
   echo ('<input type="checkbox" name="choice[' . $row["question_id"] . ']" value="1" /> ' . $row["question_text"] . '<br />';
}
echo '<br />';
echo '<input type="submit" value="submit" /></form>';
```

Then you can iterate thru the values with a `foreach` loop in `next.php`.

```
echo ('<ul>');
foreach ($_GET["choice"] as $key => $value){
    echo ('<li>' . $key . ' is ticked</li>');
}
echo ('</ul>');
```

Note that the array's **keys** hold the real information here,values wil only contain the number `1`.

Take a look ath the source of resulting HTML. This is not theonly possible solution but good for learning purposes.

Comment: Hi,thanks.But i get this error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\next.php on line 6
Line 6 is at the foreach ($_POST["choice"] as $key => $value){..line

Comment: @Abby Because you are using GET method with your form. You can change it to POST of hange the PHP code to `$_GET` - does not matter they just have to match.

Comment: Can i change the value in choice to something like 1,2,3 instead of the question_id ? how can i do that ?

Comment: @Abby Why don't you like this one? :) Of course you could have `value` attributes like `$row["question_id"]`, but it is easier to debug your code and understand it if you are using the least possible coomplexity, and this is the last possible coplexity.

Comment: Ahh, got the output that i want ! Thanks so much !!

Comment: @Abby It is supposed to display `question_id`-s of the ticked questions. They are transferred as the **keys** of `choice` area. See also the HTML source of the form.